# Knockout add CSS class depending on value in observableArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a very number/input heavy Knockout app and my HTML templates are generated from values contained within observableArrays to keep the HTML templates to a minimum.

However, some of the inputs (randomly positioned) that are generated into the HTML templates will need the class of 'total-val' adding to them.

The way I've gone about this is by creating a new `is_total` observable inside my `tableView` function which gets passed a value of true/false but this doesn't seem to be working.

I have created a simple/stripped down version of my current templating structure which can be viewed on the codepen below. The first table shows all the values inside `valuesArray` with no CSS observable. The second table does contain the CSS observable and as you can see; it's killed the script completely.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: value, css: { 'total-val', is_total }">
```

JS:

```
function tableView(label, value, is_total) {
  var self = this;
  self.label = ko.observable(label);
  self.value = ko.observable(value);
  self.is_total = ko.observable(is_total);
}

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.valuesArray = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.valuesArray.push(new tableView('one', 123, false));
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqElr

Comment: Are you sure that you've posted the right codepen? Because I can only see one table... anyway you should always include the relevant part of your code in the question question because if codepen is down it will be hard to understand...

Comment: You just have typo in `data-bind="value: value, css: { 'total-val': is_total }"` use `:` instead of the comma...

Comment: And uncomment `self.is_total` in the `tableView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your using a comma in your css binding, replace it with a colon.

```
<table data-bind="foreach: valuesArray">
  <tr>
    <td><span data-bind="text: label"></span></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: value, css: { 'total-val': is_total }"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Those pesky commas... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate

```
<input data-bind="value: value, style: { 'total-val', is_total }">
```

also it is recommended not to use hyphen so it would be better if you convert it to

```
<input data-bind="value: value, style: { 'totalval', is_total }">
```

look at documentation
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html

```
Note: Applying styles whose names aren’t legal JavaScript variable names

If you want to apply a font-weight or text-decoration style, or any other style whose  
name isn’t a legal JavaScript identifier (e.g., because it contains a hyphen), you must 
use the JavaScript name for that style. For example, 

Don’t write { font-weight: someValue }; do write { fontWeight: someValue }
Don’t write { text-decoration: someValue }; do write { textDecoration: someValue }
```